# Solution/Build Ratio

Tags: git, tfs, devops

Being new to DevOps/TFS/Git, I'm trying to better understand The Way of Things™.

Having just completed my first successful TFS build—after getting past the infamous *'Visual Studio on the build server'* requirement—I'm ready to move on to learning about NuGet Packaging and Release Management. This is exciting and I'm charged.

Before I get too far down the path, however, I'd like to check up on my understanding of the general rules of engagement with all of this.

Unless I'm mistaken, it appears that we can have only one repository per build definition; following that, only one Visual Studio solution per repository. So if we want, say, three build definitions for a given application—Dev, Staging and Release—this seems like things can get bogged down pretty quickly.

Am I correct in my initial impression that we're going to want to work up a new set of build definitions for each new application we want to roll? That's a lot of definitions, but if that's the way it's supposed to work I'll go with it.

**EDIT**

I see there's a vote to close due to lack of clarity. I'd hoped my question was clear, but I'll try to improve it a bit nonetheless.

What I'm trying to find out is whether or not the correct/most efficient way to configure this is to create a new set of build definitions for each new application/solution. This seems like it would lead to Build Definition Bloat (BDB) pretty quickly, so I'm hoping I'm incorrect in my initial impressions. I'm hoping instead that there's a way to point multiple repositories to a single set of build definitions.

That'd be my exact question, then... is there a way to link multiple repositories to a single set of Dev/Staging/Release build definitions?

Comment: This is probably going to get closed because this is a **huge** area of discussion. I consult extensively in this area and there's no simple, cut-and-dry correct answer to anything you're asking. It's all subject to business requirements, your application portfolio, and the maturity of software development practices at your organization.

Comment: @DanielMann: I see! So then it must be possible to do so—that is, send multiple repos to a single build definition. Yes?

Comment: what makes you think you should only have 1 solution per repository? Also you should be building an artifact that is deployed to all environments so you shouldn't care about dev / staging / prod. If you're using TFS 2015, use build v.next. If you're using earlier versions, forget TFS for builds, it's awful. Look at Jenkins / TeamCity.

Comment: @JamesReed: 1) To keep BDB down to a minimum, if possible. 2) You lost me there I'm afraid. 3) vNext. Seems I've dodged a bullet with this one.

Comment: 1. If by BDB you mean Build Definition Bloat, just because a solution is in a repo doesn't mean you have to build it. You could have 50 solutions in a repo and have a separate build for each one. no need for a separate repo. 2. at the end of a build, you should have a package that can be deployed to any environment. You then use a release management tool (MS-RM, Octopus Deploy, etc) to push the package to the environment and set any environment specific config (connection strings, web service endpoints etc)

Comment: @JamesReed: OK, it's starting to come clearer now. Thanks. *Release Management* is where the Dev/Staging/Release config goes, not Build. But the original concern still applies—is it possible to point multiple repos to a single build (to reduce the maintenance load)? Or is `repo->build` simply a 1:1 relationship and that's just the way it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to automate the deployment and testing of your software in multiple environments (Dev, Staging and Release).

[Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/getting-started/understand-rm), which is a service in Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server (update 2 and later) that helps you achieve this goal.

Using Release Management, you can either fully automate the delivery of your software all the way to production, or set up semi-automated processes with approvals and on-demand deployments. Check more information at website: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/overview

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I was confusing Build Definitions with Release Management. So instead we end up with a mountain of RM configurations—so be it :-) Given this, however, the need to keep BDs to a minimum is all the more pressing. Can a BD support more than one repository?

Comment: In a Release Definition, you can link multiple artifact sources to the same release definition: https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-artifacts#link-multiple-artifact-sources. In a Git Build Definition, you can only select one repository in your team project